# How to create SQL date object in a desired format ( MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM ) in Java?

Tags: java, sql, datetime

In the database server, the format of the date column is MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM

How can I create the SQL date object to send to database in the same format mentioned above?

Type of the database column is DATE. I am using Oracle Database 12C : SQL.

Comment: What is the type of the database column (e.g. DATE) and what is it the database type (e.g. PostgreSQL)

Comment: Type of the database column is DATE.

Comment: And, I am using Oracle Database  12C Version.

Comment: Dates don't have a format in the database.

Answer (score 3):

`DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` columns do **not** have "a format".

As your value apparently contains a time, you should use `LocalDateTime` or `java.sql.Timestamp` to retrieve that value.

Something like:

```
String sql = "select the_timstamp_column from the_table";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
  LocalDateTime tsValue = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class);
}
```

But still not all JDBC drivers support that, so the second best solution is to use `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
String sql = "select the_timstamp_column from the_table";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
  java.sql.Timestamp tsValue = rs.getTimestamp(1);
}
```

In both cases you can format the value of `tsValue` anyway you like in your Java code.